# Ler txt e gerar um novo com ; no final de cada linha

Tags: php, txt

Criei um sistema que importa os nomes gerado em TXT, porem o sistema interpreta o **;** no final de cada linha e grava no banco, porem o sistema comercial do meu cliente, exporta os dados sem o **;** no final, o pior que e um sistema de telemarketing que gera arquivos de quase 5000 mil nomes por dia!

**O arquivo fica desta forma:**

```
marcos
fulano
ciclano
beltrano
```

Preciso que o PHP leia esta arquivo, e gere um novo, porem com ; no final

**Ficaria assim**

```
marcos;
fulano;
ciclano;
beltrano;
```

Alguém me dá uma luz, e não consegui achar um exemplo que leia e altere depois grave!

Comment: Os nomes ficam separados por espaço ou por quebra de linha?

Comment: @JuniorNunes7, era um erro na formatação da pergunta. Os nomes são separados por linha.

Comment: Se você já tem quebras de linha, pra que precisa do `;` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Se você tiver separando os nomes por quebra de linha você pode usar isso aqui:

```
$file = fopen('./file.txt','r');
$document = fread($file, filesize('./file.txt'));
$formatedDocument = str_replace("\n", '; ', $document);

echo $formatedDocument;

fclose($file);
```

Dessa forma você abre o arquivo que você quer formatar com o `fopen`, tu lê o arquivo com o `fread` e depois usa o `str_replace` pra detectar todas as quebras de linhas do texto lido e substituir por ponto e vírgula + espaço, ficando no formato que você espera.

E para escrever em um novo arquivo você pode usar:

```
$newFile = fopen("./new-files/new-file.txt", "a");

$write = fwrite($newFile, $formatedDocument);

fclose($newFile);
```

OBS.: Preste atenção nas permissões de escrita da pasta que você vai salvar o novo arquivo, se não tiver com as permissões certas o script não funcionará.

OBS2.: Caso os nomes no arquivo a ser lido estejam separados por espaço, você pode substituir o `str_replace` por `str_replace(' ', '; ', $document);` que vai funcionar corretamente.

Comment: E no caso de ser um nome composto? A solução já não se aplica. Pelo exemplo na pergunta, é separado por uma quebra de linha, então você poderia adicionar essa opção na sua resposta.

Comment: A pergunta antes estava separada por espaço, por causa da formatação, já corrigiram, vou editar a resposta!

Answer (score 1):

Valew Junior, sua resposta me deu noção de como trabalhar aqui, o sistema separa por ; não sera necessario a quebra de linha, então deixei ele escrever um na frente do outro, sem problema, e deu certo

A unica coisa que alterei foi a quebra de linha de \n para \r

```
 $arquivo = "arquivo.txt";
$fp = fopen($arquivo,'r');
$document = fread($fp, filesize($arquivo));
$formatedDocument = str_replace("\r", ';', $document);
$escreve = fwrite($fp, $formatedDocument); 
fclose($fp); 
$arquivo_new = fopen("novo_".$arquivo, "w");
$texto = $formatedDocument;
fwrite($arquivo_new, $texto);
fclose($arquivo_new);
unlink($arquivo);
```